# What does the variable $n$ mean in the frequency of oscillation of drops?

Tags: terminology, notation, frequency, oscillators, surface-tension

I am currently working on a project to find how the frequency of oscillation of a water droplet falling through air depends on its surface tension and radius. I came across Lord Rayleigh's formulas:

[image]

[image]

$o$ is the surface tension of the drop, $f$ is the frequency, $p$ is the density of the drop substance (density of water for a water droplet), and $R$ is the radius of the water droplet, assuming that its a sphere.
I don't quite understand why the the two formulas are different. And more importantly, what does the variable, $n$, represent?

Comment: $n$ denotes the oscilllation mode. The first equation could be only for the lowest mode, and probably for different shapes.

Comment: What exactly is the oscillation mode? Does it relate to the Beard and Chuang model?

Comment: A oscillation mode is an eigen state satisfies the equation and the boundary condition. Usually, it relates to the number of nodes (or nodal lines).

Comment: Okay. So what would be an ideal oscillation mode for the frequency of oscillation of droplets? How would I find values of  which satisfies the equation?

Comment: Here an illustration of some eigen modes https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Eigenmodes-of-hemispherical-drops-predicted-by-the-theory-of-Rayleigh-and-Lamb-are_fig1_256607382

but, it depend on the differential equation and boundary condition. Different models have different result.

Comment: So, how do the variables _l_ and _k_ relate to _n_, the oscillation mode?

Comment: Each person has his own symbols. It is a two-dimesional simulation, requires two  numbers to specify an eigen mode. There are various differential equations employed to describe the ocsillation of droplet. You have first to make up your model, then collect the previous calculations using the same equation. Before that, these details are not important.

Comment: Okay thanks! How would I start of by making a model? I looked at the Beard and Chuang model. Could you help me understand this? In the diagram, what do two number axes represent?

Comment: Check his paper: PHYSICAL REVIEW E 88, 023015 (2013). The two parameters are defined in Eq.(2) to specify a Legendre function $P_k^l(\cos\theta)$.

Comment: I just saw the paper. It seems that 4 pages later, they found a formula for _n_ in terms of _l_ and _k_. I am a bit confused between the difference between equation 1 and 5 in the paper.